# Freely available resource hacking applications

Tags: tools, windows, dll, executable, pe-resources

I am using Resource Hacker as a tool to extract out resources like icon, images, etc. from `.dll` or `.exe` file. In addition, I am using it to crack some small Windows application. However, it does not work with all Win32 Application, especially with those that are zipped by `.exe` compressor.

Are there any other open source applications, that I can use to crack and extract resources out of `.dll` and `.exe` files?

Comment: Regarding compressed binaries, you will probably need to [unpack them](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/72/unpacking-binaries) before you can use tools on them.

Comment: Though not open source, another option is Resource Hacker:  http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the previously suggested resource editors aren't to your liking, you can find descriptions and reviews of several resource editors here: [http://www.woodmann.com/collaborative/tools/index.php/Category:Resource_Editors](https://web.archive.org/web/20200628165509/http://www.woodmann.com/collaborative/tools/index.php/Category:Resource_Editors)

In case you have trouble accessing that page (as per the comments below), here is the list of resource editors as of 2022-10-12:

- [PE Explorer](http://www.heaventools.com/overview.htm) (paid, discontinued, last updated 2012)
- [Resource Hacker (Reshacker)](http://angusj.com/resourcehacker) (proprietary)
- [Explorer Suite](https://ntcore.com/?page_id=388) (proprietary,last updated 2012)
- [Anolis Resourcer](https://web.archive.org/web/20150621043201/http://www.anol.is/resourcer/) (FLOSS, discontinued, last updated 2009, down) - [archived download](https://archive.org/download/sylirana_ms_codeplex_zips/tars/mscodeplex-a-3.tar/.%2Fanolis.zip)
- [eXeScope](https://web.archive.org/web/20150717082629/http://hp.vector.co.jp/authors/VA003525/Eindex.htm)
- [ResFixer](https://web.archive.org/web/20181222005849/http://www.woodmann.com/collaborative/tools/index.php/ResFixer) (last updated 2008)
- <s>[Resourcer for .NET](http://www.aisto.com/roeder/dotnet/)</s> (no longer available)
- [StringEditor](https://web.archive.org/web/20181222005845/http://www.woodmann.com/collaborative/tools/index.php/StringEditor)
- [Stud_PE](http://www.cgsoftlabs.ro/studpe.html) (last updated 2012)
- [XN Resource Editor](https://stefansundin.github.io/xn_resource_editor/) (FLOSS, basically discontinued)
- [RisohEditor](https://github.com/katahiromz/RisohEditor) (FLOSS, active)
- Honorable mention: [ResourcesExtract](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/resources_extract.html) can mass-extract resources

PS: [Woodman.com](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/14588/245) was referenced a few times above and archived versions of it can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20220330081653/http://www.woodmann.com/forum/index.php)

Answer (score 4):

You can use **ResEdit** which is a resource editor for Windows programs available in both 32 Bit and 64 Bit versions.

You can download this freeware application from this [link](http://www.resedit.net/)

Answer (score 4):

- **[XN Resource Editor](https://stefansundin.github.io/xn_resource_editor/) (open source [under MPL](https://web.archive.org/web/20120307192859fw_/http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/delphi_2006.htm); see also [here](https://github.com/stefansundin/xn_resource_editor/issues/5))**

[image]

- **[Resource Editor](http://melander.dk/reseditor/) (free)**

[image]

- **[ResEd](https://code.google.com/p/theunknownones/wiki/ResEd) (a free and open-source [expert for Delphi](http://web.archive.org/web/20140403183440/http://code.google.com/p/theunknownones/wiki/ResEd))**

Comment: Not true that it's not under a free license, [see here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120307192859fw_/http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/delphi_2006.htm)

Answer (score 4):

I personally recommend [CFF Explorer](http://www.ntcore.com/exsuite.php) for reversing purposes as it provides a large volume of additional information on a binary.

[image: CFF Explorer]

Answer (score 1):

I am not so sure what you mean with "*zipped by .exe compressor*", but if you mean packed executables, then the easiest to EXTRACT packed resources is as follows:

1. Run the executable, preferably in Virtual Machine.
2. Dump it using any memory dumper e.g. "Virtual Section Dumper".
3. Use a PE editor e.g. `Stud_PE` to fix the section table by shrinking the value of the `NumberOfSections` field into only one. (One big section) and adjusting Raw/VirtualSize and Raw/VirtualOffset accordingly.
4. Use Resource Hacker.

**N.B.**: You can try with more than one Resource editor *e.g.* ResEdit since many resource editors out there follow weird rules for PE header as they only expect typical PE headers.

Ironically, one resource editor expects the resources to be embedded in a section named `.rsrc`, otherwise it rejects them. Others don't see resources if embedded in a section marked as `IMAGE_SCN_CNT_UNINITIALIZED_DATA 0x80`.

One the other hand if you can attach to the running process without problems (No or bypassed Anti-Attaching tricks), you can use OllyDbg v1.10 for that as follows:

1. After attach, Select "View" then "Memory" <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>). You will get list of sections beside other memory blocks.
2. Spot the resources section. *e.g.* `.rsrc`. <kbd>Right-Click</kbd> the target section and "View all resources". You will then a list of well-sorted resources.
3. <kbd>Right-Click</kbd> whichever resource you want and select "dump". A new window will pop up.
4. Right-Click inside the hex view of the new window and select "Backup" and "Save data to file".

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes... I mean packed execuable files, anyway thanks for your contribution.