# what does VA and OEP means? and How does IAT be fixed manually?

Tags: binary-analysis, unpacking

in the context of reversing a packed binary, what does VA and OEP means? and How can IAT be fixed manually?

Comment: This is too broad and actually 3 different questions. Please separate the questions and add more information such as what you already now, what did you read, what are the specific points that you don't understand. See the [How to Ask](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

VA = virtual address. See [VA (Virtual Address) & RVA (Relative Virtual Address)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170843/va-virtual-address-rva-relative-virtual-address)

OEP = original entry point. See [Unpacking binaries in a generic way](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/72/unpacking-binaries-in-a-generic-way/91#91)

> How does IAT be fixed manually?

This question was asked and answered here: [How would I go about rebuilding the IAT of a packed executable?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/21540/how-would-i-go-about-rebuilding-the-iat-of-a-packed-executable)

Have a look at [Scylla](https://github.com/NtQuery/Scylla) as well.

Comment: I dont understand the example for IAT you provided, how does he know where to find IAT addresses?