# General unpacking of packed malware

Tags: malware, unpacking

I did a brief survey on malware unpacking and I found several theses on automated general unpacking:Eureka, PolyUnpack, omniUnpack, Malware Normalization.

However, these theses are written years ago and I don't think these methods still work. A basic assumption of these methods is an unpacker routine restore whole protected code at a time. Thus, we can get original code dumping a certain memory region when an unpacker routine finishes its work.

When it comes to more sophisticated packer (such as [Maya's veil](http://bitlackeys.org/#maya)), it doesn't reveal whole protected code. As far as I know an attempt to attack this problem is to [distinguish between code that performs unpacking routine and code does not](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5645447/) and I think this is not really unpacking.

Only way to unpacking sophisticated packers is manually reversing it?

Thank you.

Comment: Even though there is sophisticated malware out there, there is always unsophisticated malware for which those old techniques might still work.

Answer (score 2):

You actually have more than one option in this case:

1. RE of sophisticated packer
2. Wait for someone else to RE the sophisticated packer and publish the method/tool. Maybe ask in this community?
3. Ask the author of sophisticated packer to provide the unpacker [buy one?]
4. Ask the author of packed program to provide it to you with no sophisticated packer applied.

Hope it help :)

D.L.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know I can write an unpacker for a specific packer.

Comment: I'm going to do further research to figure out a way to create generic unpacker

Comment: @kensuke this may be helpful: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/72/unpacking-binaries-in-a-generic-way